# apache rewrite to different domain subfolder without changing the address in browser url

Tags: apache-http-server, user-agent, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Actually we have 2 sites.

Site 1: Desktop version hosted in [http://mysite1.com] , using Apache server

Site2: Mobile version of mysite.com is hosted in [http://mobilesites.com/mysite1mobile] , using Apache server.

Now,

- if request comes from desktop browser to mysite1.com it should fetch content of [http://mysite1.com], and
- if request comes from mobile browser to mysite1.com it should fetch content of [http://mobliesites.com/mysite1mobile] , without changing address bar in browser URL

We tried like this in apache/conf/httpd.conf of mysite1.com :

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobilesites.com/mysite1mobile/$1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mobilesites.com/mysite1mobile/
</IfModule>
```

When we aceess mysite1 from mobile browser, its able forward the request but not able to map links of theme and pages inside the site.

Please help...